# Backbone JS: Fetching a collection – trouble with JSON response format

Tags: backbone.js

I have some trouble with the initial population of a collection in Backbone JS.

While developing `myCollection` didn't fetch the data from a server, I just passed it in like this:

```
app.myCollection.reset([
  { person: 'Sally'},
  { person: 'Peter'},
  { person: 'Paul'},
  { person: 'Wilma'}
]);
```

Doing a `console.log(app.myCollection);` showed me that the collection was correctly populated since it's `length` was 4:

```
s {length: 4, models: Array[4], _byId: Object}
```

Now I want to fetch the data from a server, the response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "person": "Sally"
    },
    {
        "person": "Peter"
    },
    {
        "person": "Paul"
    },
    {
        "person": "Wilma"
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, something goes wrong, since the `length` attribute now is 0, although I can find the data inside the object.

```
s {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object}
```

I do it like this:

```
app.myCollection.fetch({reset: true});
```

To me it looks like only the outer array gets "mapped" to a model, instead of every object inside the array.

What can I do to prevent this?

**Edit**
As suggested in the comments, I included an "id" attribute to the response. Now, it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "person": "Sally"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "person": "Peter"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "person": "Paul"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "person": "Wilma"
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, something still isn't right, as the collection now looks like this:

```
s {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object}
_byId: Object
length: 4
models: Array[4]
__proto__: s
```

So you see, one length is 0, the other one 4. Could this be because I just link to a json file currently?

Comment: Set the `idAttribute` to `"person"` on your collection before fetching. Either that or have your server respond with a unique `"id"` attribute for each object in the response array.

Comment: actually, you'll want to set it on the model, not the collection. also, be certain your `person` values are unique

Comment: @idbehold Thanks, I just included an "id" attribute as this seems to be more clear and safe, but the collection still looks weird. I've edited the question.

Comment: @StephenThomas Thank you for the tip, I decided to add an `id` attribute instead, but the collection still is a bit off. Maybe you could have a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch is asynchronous so maybe when you log in your console the data isn't fetched yet? Do you use a success callback function on your fetch?

```
    app.myCollection.fetch({reset: true},success: function() {console.log(app.myCollection);});
```

Comment: Thats it, Now it's working! I didn't realize it was asynchronous even when linked to a json file. But of course it makes sense as fetch fires an AJAX request. Thank you!